# Odoo 9 - Dynamic Selection field depending context

Tags: python, dynamic, field, selection, odoo

I am stuck with this problem anybody could help ?
I would like to get a list of present product in stock.pack.operation for a certain picking_id. 
I pass the picking_id using a context via the form view.
When I try to setup the Selection Field i got nothing but when I try with a Char field it works.

Here is the code:

```
def _default_products_list(self):
    active_id = self.env.context.get('default_picking_id', []) or []
    vals=[]
    for record in self.env['stock.pack.operation'].search([('picking_id','=',active_id)]):
        vals.extend([(record.product_id.name,record.product_id.name)])
    return vals

name = fields.Char(string='test', required=True, default=_default_products_list)
product = fields.Selection(_default_products_list, string="Product")
```

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: why would the active id be filled in that situation?, the selection fields values run when updating the module, not when you open the view.

Comment: @Toby you're right thanks for your advise I'll edit the post

Comment: @dccdany The active_id is to be the current picking id in fact there is a Many2One link into stock.picking to this new object. So active_id is pass from the view form using context when I create a new line running the module the field "name" is well populated using the _default_products_list function as declared it is displayed in the view but not the "product" selection field which remains empty . Therefore if I fix the value of active_id in the function with an existing pickind_id it works.

Comment: One field is a char, the other one is a selection, the possible selection values are not calculated when opening the view, but when restarting odoo and updating the module, it is not the same case

Comment: I get you. Thanks. So I have to figure out another way.

Comment: @dccdany you are half right the selection is calculated when rendering the view exactly not when the module is lawed.  use many2one field for this kind of situation.

Comment: @Cherif this is what I noticed therefore I miss something. I do use a Many2one against product.product at the moment it doesn't make the trick since I wanted to select only product in the stock.pack.operation of the current picking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `many2one` and add a `filter` to show only the product that are in the current `picking_id`:

```py
    @api.onchange('picking_id')
    def on_change_picking_id(self):
        """ add domain to product id to show only product that are in the current picking"""
        if self.picking_id:
            # i'm not in my compute i forget how to get list of ids from picking_id
            picking_product_ids = self.picking_id.mapped('move_lines.product_id').ids
            return {'domain': {'product_id': [('id', 'in', picking_product_ids)]}}
        else:
            # remove domain to show all products
            return {'domain': {'product_id': []}}
```

Comment: Many Thanks ! It does the job. I got the way of it works now